# How to Implement a phaser game to a specific page in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, phaser-framework

I am Creating a business app, and in this app you log in and there are five tabs below, i am trying to start a phaser game once you click create in one of the tabs, however i am new to this and their isn't much help with ionic and phaser combining. The problem i am having is i have created two divs in my index file for phaser and ionic, but i only want phaser on one of the tabs instead of overlapping on every screen. As shown in my index file.

Here is my index file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user- scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>


<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->


<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">


<style type="text/css">
  .platform-ios .manual-ios-statusbar-padding{
    padding-top:20px;
  }
  .manual-remove-top-padding{
    padding-top:0px; 
  }
  .manual-remove-top-padding .scroll{
    padding-top:0px !important;
  }
</style>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/phaser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/boot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/preload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gameover.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gametitle"></script>





<script src="lib/ionicuirouter/ionicUIRouter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
        scaleRatio = window.devicePixelRatio / 3;

    //Create a new game instance and assign it to the 'gameArea' div
    game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,   (window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio) -45 * window.devicePixelRatio, Phaser.AUTO, 'gameArea');

    //Add all states
    game.state.add("Boot", Boot);
    game.state.add("Preload", Preload);
    game.state.add("GameTitle", GameTitle);
    game.state.add("Main", Main);
    game.state.add("GameOver", GameOver);

    //Start the first state
    game.state.start("Boot");
 })();
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id='gameArea'></div>
 <div id="ionicControls" ng-app="app">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">



<ion-nav-buttons>

<ion-icon>
<img src="img/Logo (1).png" height="auto" width="35">
</ion-icon>

 </ion-nav-buttons>
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-    back">Back</ion-nav-back-button>

    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view>



    </ion-nav-view> 

    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the page i want the phaser game to start, What i am wondering is how to implement the code here so it will start up when clicked

i want phaser to start on this page

```
<ion-view title="Room Design" id="page10" class=" ">
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
<a ui-sref="tabsController.contactUs" id="roomDesign-button6" class="                       


button button-balanced  button-block ">Save</a>

</ion-content>


</ion-view>
```

I am hoping i can transfer the code that starts the game into the controller for the phaser page, however i tried that and i couldnt get it to work, pls be patient with me because i am a beginner :)

Controller for page

```
.controller('roomDesignCtrl', function($scope) {








})
```

Answer (score 0):

I like phaser.io but i don't use ionic yet, perhaps this example can help you launch your application after a click, because it uses the same design with game states

https://github.com/EnclaveGames/Monster-Wants-Candy-demo